# Visual Studio LoadLibrary() "Debug Assertion Failed"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, assertions, loadlibrary

I'm debugging a `64-bit` `C++` application in `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` but at the line

```
HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\Cpp\\Program2\\x64\\Debug\\Program2.dll");
```

I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: D:\Cpp\Program\Debug\Program.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\output.cpp
Line: 34

Expression: stream != nullptr
```

When I click `Continue` I get

```
Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Unhandled exception at 0x0F35ED76 (ucrtbased.dll) in Program.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

in `stdio.h`:

[image]

The application can be built/compiled just fine. The whole code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    /*
    * Load library in which we'll be hooking our functions.
    */
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\Cpp\\Program2\\Debug\\Program2.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        printf("The DLL could not be found.\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    /*
    * Get the address of the function inside the DLL.
    */
    HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "meconnect");
    if (addr == NULL) {
        printf("The function was not found.\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    /*
    * Hook the function.
    */
    HHOOK handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, dll, 0);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("The KEYBOARD could not be hooked.\n");
    }

    /*
    * Unhook the function.
    */
    printf("Program successfully hooked.\nPress enter to unhook the function and stop the program.\n");
    getchar();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong? The `DLL` file being loaded exists in the file system. Changing to `Release` build or `Debug` doesn't help.

When the `DLL` and the process calling `LoadLibrary()` are `32-bit` or `64-bit` I get the `Debug Assertion Failed` message. If the bit versions mismatch or the file doesn't exist, the function returns `NULL` and no `Debug Assertion Failed` message.

Comment: Press Retry to debug the application. Get a stack trace. I suspect something in `Program2.dll` is responsible.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` is a Windows API call. It doesn't use the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library (and doesn't raise debug assertions either). Consequently, the issue must be with the code that's executed as part of calling `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza, Not found the error in your code, so it would be related to the specific dll file(Program2.dll) called in your code. You could use this tool to debug your dll file:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza, Any update for this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: I will try again later